# Create Campaign through MailChimp API

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I would like to create campaign through MailChimp API. I am using below code.

```
        $data = ["recipients" => ["list_id" => "a332819b0b"], "type" => "regular", "settings" => ["subject_line" => "Subject", "title" => "Title", "reply_to" => "test@gmail.com", "from_name" => "Test"]];
        $data = json_encode($data);
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            //Sample url
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["apikey:MY_API_KEY"],
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            $response = $err;
        }

        die($response);
```

I am getting output like below.

[image]

Could anyone help me solve the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend changing your account's API key since it is meant to be private. You can [follow the steps here](https://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/api-integrations/about-api-keys#Disable-an-API-Key) to disable the key in this question and generate a new one so other people can't access your account.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it working. Simply replace the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` line with `CURLOPT_USERPWD` like this:

`CURLOPT_USERPWD => "apikey:abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us10"`

Of course, you'll want to use your own API key in there and it should work fine.